# Why does printing of a (nil) map in golang yield a non "<nil>" result?

Tags: dictionary, go, null

In golang, if you create a struct with a map in it, which is uninitialized, printing the map yields a non `<nil>` string.

Why does "print" of a nil map output "map[]" instead of `<nil>` ?

```
// Assume above there is a struct, a.AA, which is created but which otherwise
// has not created the map.
//output:
//map[]
//map[]
fmt.Println(a.AA)
fmt.Println(make(map[string]int64))
```

Comment: That's just how the formatter prints it. It's only for convenience, so having the type shown is useful (not to mention you can index from a nil map)

Comment: @JimB That's actually the answer, post it.

Answer (score 6):

It's just for making things clear. If you run this code:

```
var m map[string]int64
log.Println(m == nil)
log.Printf("%T\n", m)
```

It will print:

```
$ true
$ map[string]int64
```

So `m` is actually `nil` at this point. A `nil` value (can) have a type too and the formater uses that to print out something meaningful when possible.

A `map` behaves like a reference type in other languages. And in Go you can call methods of a struct even if its value is `nil`.

So even for your own structs, you can *implement* `fmt.Stringer` interface by just defining the `String() string` method on your struct and whenever your struct's value is `nil` you can print out something more proper than `<nil>`. Having:

```
type someData struct {
    someValue string
}

func (x *someData) String() string {
    if x == nil {
        return "NO PROPER DATA HERE!"
    }

    return x.someValue
}
```

Then if we run:

```
var data *someData
log.Println(data)
data = new(someData)
data.someValue = "Aloha! :)"
log.Println(data)
```

The output will be:

```
$ NO PROPER DATA HERE!
$ Aloha! :)
```

See at the first line we did not get `<nil>` as output, despite the fact that our struct pointer is `nil` at that point.

Answer (score 0):

A nil pointer is not the same as an empty (or zero) map. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value for authoritative information concerning zero values.

If you want a nil, you need a pointer, such as in the following [example](https://play.golang.org/p/IJhmHQKFqf):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var myMap map[string]int64
    fmt.Printf("myMap before assignment: %v\n", myMap)

    myMap = make(map[string]int64)
    fmt.Printf("myMap after assignment : %v\n", myMap)

    var myMapPointer *map[string]int64
    fmt.Printf("myMapPointer before assignment: %v\n", myMapPointer)

    myMapPointer = new(map[string]int64)
    fmt.Printf("myMapPointer after assignment : %v\n", myMapPointer)
}
```

This gives:

```
myMap before assignment: map[]
myMap after assignment : map[]
myMapPointer before assignment: <nil>
myMapPointer after assignment : &map[]
```

Comment: Except the documentation you cite specifically states that the zero vale of a map is `nil` https://play.golang.org/p/c6NOfiotCC